# iframe not working in ie8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe

The `iframe` tag in this script is not working in IE-Version 8 but it is working in Firefox and Chrome . Is there any replacement for the `iframe` that works in all browsers?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    document.body.onload = function () { onclick(); };

    function onclick() {
      $("#chartdiv").html('<iframe id="Reloader" style="width: 680px; height: 500px;margin-left:250px;" frameborder="0" marginwidth="1" src="charts/deptwise.htm"></iframe>');
    }; 

</script>
```

Comment: are you sure its the iframe and not the javascript thats not working? test with plain text and see if it shows up on both browsers.

Comment: Your script is a weird mix of things. Use $('body').on("click(function() { $("#chartdiv").html(...) });

Comment: yep rookie im sure no error in java script .. cuz it works fine in other browsers

Comment: the script should run in page load thats y ive written body onload yasar

Comment: that just means the other browsers happen to tolerate it, not that it is the correct way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

Try using the jQuery load function instead of the document.body.onload - I suspect IE8 is having difficulty with the onload portion:
http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: $('body').on("click(function(){ $("#chartdiv").html(('<iframe id="Reloader" style="width: 680px; height: 500px;margin-left:250px;" frameborder="0" marginwidth="1" src="charts/deptwise.htm"></iframe>')) }); --- useing this code same error

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  $("#chartdiv").html('<iframe id="Reloader" style="width: 680px; height: 500px;margin-left:250px;" frameborder="0" marginwidth="1" src="charts/deptwise.htm"></iframe>');
});
```

will likely work better

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/UBWz3/) tested in Chrome FX, IE8 and IE9

if you want to have it execute on click of the body:

```
$(function() {
  $("body").on("click",function() {
    $("#chartdiv").html('<iframe id="Reloader" style="width: 680px; height: 500px;margin-left:250px;" frameborder="0" marginwidth="1" src="http://msdn.com"></iframe>');
  });
});​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/h93vV/)

Comment: I have used yur code plung but the same thing . works fine with firefox

Comment: thanks plung i hav tested ur code ... when the src ="msdn.com" it works good but when src is a htm file src="charts/deptwise.htm". it is not coming in IE

Comment: that is highly unlikely. Can you load the file from <a href="charts/deptwise.htm">Click</a> and see if it is what you expect? Also click F12 and see if there are any comments in the console

Comment: Even the Html file does not display in IE .. Actually My output is amcharts ... hope you know what amcharts are ...

Comment: No idea. That seems to be the problem then. http://www.amcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=6500